# Dataset with disproportionately more of a single label than any other

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, data-cleaning, orange

I'm using the data analysis software Orange to analyze rows of data with labels $\{H, T,L\}$. $T$ is the neutral state of the system I'm trying to model so data is almost always labeled with $T$.  This leads to an extremely high $97$% classification accuracy, that is untrue.  Almost no datapoint with an $H, L$ actually gets labeled with an $H, L$ respectively by the neural net.  The neural net is doing what's logical: flatten everything to $T$ since that occurs most of the time.  How can I repair this situation?

Comment: There are downsampling and oversampling approaches to mitigate the imbalance. There are also cost-sensitive approaches, but I'm not sure if they can be applied with neural networks. Also consider computing recall metrics, they should be very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways:

1. Oversample the under-represented class.
   issue: Leads to very constrained boundaries (not smooth) around the under-represented class
2. Weigh the loss coming from under-represented class more than over-represented class. If you think about it, this is mathematically doing the same thing as 1
3. Use SMOTE ([here](https://beckernick.github.io/oversampling-modeling/)) (i recommend this). Basically samples additional points randomly from lines joining nearest under-represented classes and increases the dataset size accordingly. [scikit contrib implementation of smote](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html)

There are other ways but they offer very marginal improvement over SMOTE